# How does PCA gives centers for the Kmeans algorithm in scikit learn

Tags: scikit-learn, k-means, pca

I'm looking at this example code given on [Scikit Kmeans digit example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_kmeans_digits.html)

There is the following code in this script :

```
# in this case the seeding of the centers is deterministic, hence we run the
# kmeans algorithm only once with n_init=1
pca = PCA(n_components=n_digits).fit(data)
bench_k_means(KMeans(init=pca.components_, n_clusters=n_digits, n_init=1),
          name="PCA-based",
          data=data)
```

Why are the eigen vectors used as initial centers and is there any intuition for this?

Comment: also try http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a stackexchange link [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/43099/how-to-explain-the-connection-between-svd-and-clustering), and also some discussion on the [PCA wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis).

There is also an [informative mailing list discussion](http://sourceforge.net/p/scikit-learn/mailman/scikit-learn-general/thread/20101105060441.GA19337@phare.normalesup.org/)  about the creation of this example.

All of these threads point back to [this paper](http://ranger.uta.edu/~chqding/papers/KmeansPCA1.pdf) among [others](http://ranger.uta.edu/~chqding/papers/Zha-Kmeans.pdf). In a brief, this paper says that there is a strong relationship between the subspace found by SVD (as seen in PCA) and the optimal cluster centers we seek in K-means, along with associated proofs. The key sentence comes in the lower right of the first page - "We prove that principal
components are actually the continuous solution of the cluster membership indicators in the K-means clustering method, i.e., the PCA dimension reduction automatically performs data clustering according to the K-means objective function".

What this amounts to is that SVD/PCA eigenvectors *should* be very good initializers for K-Means. The authors of this paper actually take things a step further, and project the data into the eigenspace for both of their experiments, then cluster there.

Comment: Thank you Kyle for the explanation. I was not aware of the mailing lists archive, that is an excellent pointer.

Comment: What this in my opinion demonstrates is that k-means doesn't actually discover *structure* in the data (i.e. clustering). It's more a projection technique (like PCA).

Comment: albeit a more flexible one. Orthogonality constraints lead to uninterpretable vectors quickly.